# Why is Sony Xperia E not supported in Play store for my Phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, publishing

I have Phonegap app, when I upload it to Play store for publish, I see, that APK has these features:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

and these requirements:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I don't see a reason why [Sony Xperia E](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_e-5149.php) is not supported. Can anybody give me some details ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell the app's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, [the SONY Xperia E has a fixed-focus camera](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_e-review-922.php), and therefore you are failing on your requirement for autofocus.

If you do not absolutely need autofocus, add a `<uses-feature>` element to say that autofocus is not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```